# IOS: double tap gesture in an half of self.view

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to recognizer an UITapGesture (add this gesture at self.view) only in left half in my self.view (landscape) what's the way to do it?

Comment: look here, you will see the solution:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to test for this in your gesture recognizer handling method. So when you detect the double tap have a conditional that tests to see if your origin point (which you can get from the reconigzer's `locationInView` method) has an `X` value that is less than half your view's width. If it does you know the tap is on the left hand side, and then you can proceed.

Comment: finally I use gesture point, and two views, then if gesture point is inside one of these views I do an action and I solve my problem

Comment: That's another option, although if you don't fancy messing around with multiple views doing the math is probably the easier method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func doubleTapped() {
        if doubleTapGesture.location(in: self.view).x >= self.view.frame.width / 2 {
            print("DEBUG: Double tapped on the right side")
        } else {
            print("DEBUG: Double tapped on the left side")
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).